# Вопрос по PHP, не выдает самое большое число

Tags: php

Почему выдает 22 если самое большое число это 51?

```html
    $a = 1;
    $b = 22;
    $c = 51;

    if ($a > $b && $c){
        echo ($a);
    }
    else if ($b > $a && $c){
        echo ($b);
    }
    else if ($c > $b && $a){
        echo ($c);
    }
```

Вопрос второй, а почему тут всегда true? если все числа четные

```
$a = 12;
$b = 22;
$c = 52;

if ($a%3==0 || $b%3==0 || $c%3==0){
    echo ('true');
}
else{
    echo ("false");
}
```

Comment: Откуда ж вы такой синтакс постоянно берете.

Comment: Это все из за этого знака $, :D

Comment: @Мнебезсахара )))))

Comment: С математикой видимо совсем плохо. 12 делится на 3 __нацело__.

Comment: а мы так проверяли четность и нечетность чисел :D и тогда работало

Comment: Четность и нечетность проверяется делением на 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нету такого выражения как $a > $b && $c. Есть как $a > $b && $a > $c. Выражение которое вы написали означает *если а больше б и с != 0(null, undefined...)*

Второй вопрос:$a%3 == 0, потом используете *или, или*. 1 или 0 или 0 то получится 1

Comment: Ну я так и писал если один из трех чисел нечетный то вывод true, но не работает

Comment: @Мнебезсахара нечетный это !($a%2 == 0).

Comment: @Мнебезсахара вы написали если ВСЕ делятся нацело на 3 то true

Comment: а ты молоток) пойду на с++ поработаю :D (это  в шутку)

Comment: @Мнебезсахара я уже запутался где шутки а где серьезно)

Comment: забей :D сам тоже

Comment: @Мнебезсахара Если проблема решена - дай галочку:) Если нет - пиши что не ясно

Comment: после решении нужно еще 10 минут активировался кнопка, щясь дам, я всегда даю галочку)